How to add an ArrayList in a Superclass using Getters and Setters from a subclass

Here is the super class:

public abstract class ImperialCluster implements Serializable,Clusterable {
    
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String clusterType;
    private ArrayList<Alpha> alphas;
    private ArrayList<Beta> betas;
    private ArrayList<Gamma> gammas;
    
    public ImperialCluster() {
        this.alphas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.betas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.gammas = new ArrayList<>();
        
    }

    public String getClusterType() {
        return clusterType;
    }

    public ArrayList<Alpha> getAlphas() {
        return alphas;
    }

    public ArrayList<Beta> getBetas() {
        return betas;
    }

    public ArrayList<Gamma> getGammas() {
        return gammas;
    }

    public void setClusterType(String clusterType) {
        this.clusterType = clusterType;
    }

    public void setAlphas(ArrayList<Alpha> alphas) {
        this.alphas = alphas;
    }

    public void setBetas(ArrayList<Beta> betas) {
        this.betas = betas;
    }

    public void setGammas(ArrayList<Gamma> gammas) {
        this.gammas = gammas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.clusterType 
                + "\nCluster Type: " + this.clusterType 
                + "Alpha Particles: " + this.alphas.size() 
                + "Beta Particles: " + this.betas.size()
                + "Gamma Particles: " + this.gammas.size()
                + gammas + ", getClusterType()=" + getClusterType() + ", getAlphas()=" + getAlphas() + ", getBetas()="
                + getBetas() + ", getGammas()=" + getGammas() + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()="
                + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }   
}


Here is the subclass:

public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Meson() {
        Alpha A = new Alpha();
        Beta B = new Beta();
        Gamma G = new Gamma();
        getAlphas().add(A);
        this.setAlphas(getAlphas().add(A));
        this.setBetas(getBetas().add(B));
        this.setClusterType("Meson");
    }

    @Override
    public void displayCluster() {
        System.out.println(toString());
        
    }

}

I wanted to add an alpha object to the alphas ArrayList and a Beta object to the betas ArrayList.
this.setAlphas(getAlphas().add(A));
provides an error because the .add(A) returns a boolean.
What is a work around?

You're already adding an alpha with getAlphas().add(A). Why are you trying to add it two different ways, one of which doesn't work?

By the way, variable names should start with a lowercase letter (unless naming a constant). So your A, B, C should be a, b, c.

There's a few ways you could achieve that.
Change the visibility of your Arraylist variables.
First, the easiest way would be to change the visibility of your array lists to be protected. The protected visibility allow subclass to access a parent class property, but not external classes. By having protected property, you could simply call the add function on the array list directly:
public abstract class ImperialCluster implements Serializable,Clusterable {
   /** ... **/
   protected ArrayList<Alpha> alphas;
   /** ... **/
}

public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {
    public Meson() {
        /** ... **/
        this.alphas.add(A);
        /** ... **/
    }
}

Split the add operation into three steps
The other way would be to split your add function call, and the setAlphas call into three separate steps, and by using a variable.
The first step would be to fetch and assign the alphas arraylist to a temporary variable:
public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {
    public Meson() {
        /** ... **/
        ArrayList currentAlphas = getAlphas();
        /** ... **/
    }
}

Then, you can push your new alpha into the temporary variable, like you are already doing.
public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {
    public Meson() {
        /** ... **/
        Alpha A = new Alpha()
        ArrayList currentAlphas = getAlphas();
        currentAlphas.add(A)
        /** ... **/
    }
}

Finally, you use the setAlphas like before, but with the updated temporary variable. This will update the alphas in the parent class to be like the temporary variable that you just created.
public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {
    public Meson() {
        /** ... **/
        Alpha A = new Alpha()
        ArrayList currentAlphas = getAlphas();
        currentAlphas.add(A)
        this.setAlphas(currentAlphas)
        /** ... **/
    }
}

Create a new addAlpha function
One final way to bypass this issue could be to create a new function, in your parent class, that would handle the add all by itself. Then, you only need to call this new function with your A variable and let it handle pushing the value in the alphas ArrayList.
public abstract class ImperialCluster implements Serializable,Clusterable {
   /** ... **/
   public void addAlpha(Alpha A) {
      this.alphas.add(A) 
   }
   /** ... **/
}

public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {
    public Meson() {
        /** ... **/
        Alpha A = new Alpha()
        this.addAlpha(A)
        /** ... **/
    }
}


There is no need to change the visibility of the lists. Any caller, whether in the subclass or otherwise, can access them by calling the getters. OP is already adding an alpha to the list with getAlphas().add(A), and can add a beta the same way.

There's no need to set Alfas to the parent class. It didn't change during execution.

Type mismatch

this.setAlphas(getAlphas().add(A));
provides an error because the .add(A) returns a boolean.

The methods List#add & Collection#add are documented as returning a boolean. To quote the Javadoc:

Returns: true if this collection changed as a result of the call

So your code effectively the same as this:
ArrayList<Alpha> arrayListAlphas = this.getAlphas() ;
boolean added = arrayListAlphas.add( A ) ;
this.setAlphas( added ) ;  // ⬅️ Compiler error. Mismatched types.

That list line provokes a compiler error. You cannot pass a boolean value  (added here) to a method defined as taking an argument of type ArrayList (setAlphas(ArrayList<Alpha> alphas)).
Returning a reference to a list, not a copy of a list
And very important here, a point you seem to not understand: Your setAlphas call in your example is redundant, as you have already handed out a reference to the ArrayList contained in your object. When the calling programmer added to the returned list, that addition went into the original list, the one and only list, still stored within the Meson/ImperialCluster object. Your getAlphas method does not hand out a copy of the list, it hands out the list itself.
Another type mismatch
By the way, passing A to List.add fails. Look at the code example above again:
ArrayList<Alpha> arrayListAlphas = this.getAlphas() ;
boolean added = arrayListAlphas.add( A ) ;   // ⬅️ This too is a compiler error. Must pass single element, not a collection of elements. 
this.setAlphas( added ) ; 

In that second line, we must pass an individual element to that method, an element to be added to the collection. If we want to add a bunch of elements, a collection of elements, even if the collection is empty, use Collection#addAll method rather than add method.
Break encapsulation with public
You asked:

What is a work around?

Well, your whole approach here is screwy. The entire point of accessor methods (getters & setters) is to provide encapsulation, to not provide outside calling programmers direct access to the innards of your object. Yet here you hand out references to the list within your object, let them change that list, and even let them replace that list.
If you really want to provide such wide-open access to a member field of your class, just make the member field public rather than private. Then delete your getters & setters, as they are a waste of code.
public abstract class ImperialCluster implements Serializable,Clusterable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String clusterType;
    public ArrayList<Alpha> alphas;  // ⬅️ Make `public` rather than `private`. 
…

Now calling programmers have direct access.
public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Meson() {
        this.alphas = new Alpha(); 
        …
        this.setClusterType("Meson");
    }
…

Such direct access is technically permitted, but recommended. You are free to break encapsulation if you wish. But doing so defeats the purpose of object-oriented programming. Your codebase will be fragile, future changes will be more complicated and likely error-prone.
Superclass constructor called implicitly
Finally, the code in Meson constructor does nothing useful, as the superclass constructor is implicitly called. The superclass constructor has already installed an empty list of Alpha. So your subclass’ constructor is simply replacing that empty list with a second empty list. The implicit superclass constructor call is effectively the same as the following code where you could write a call to super():
public class Meson extends ImperialCluster {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Meson() {
        super() ;  // ⬅️ Making explicit the otherwise implicit call to superclass’ constructor. 
        this.alphas = new Alpha(); 
        …
        this.setClusterType("Meson");
    }
…

